# how to access columns which are indexed from JAVA code?

Tags: java, sql, oracle10g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use index in select statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593765/how-to-use-index-in-select-statement)

Let me be specific:

I have certain tables x and y created in oracle 10g Database. I have indexed certain columns in my tables for faster retrieval of records using `CREATE INDEX` statement.

I have Java code which accesses these tables to retrieve data using prepared statement object. However I am unclear on how to retrieve data from these indexed tables. Please help. A code snippet will be really helpful.

Comment: For what purpose do you want to get this data of indexes? Indexes are created merely to speed up your queries.

Comment: can you show what you have done

Comment: @ niraj deshmukh.Here is code snippet: - 1. For Database- CREATE INDEX index_name ON x_table (name, city); /* I have created index on columns name and city of table x_table*/. I wish to retrieve data from indexed columns of this table using select statement through my java code. My Select statement:- select * from x_table where name = "<value>" . My question is :- Do i need to follow any particular rules for retrieving data from indexed columns or is it done normal way as specified in above line. Please inform me if you need to see my java code as well.

Comment: @Andrey Kapelchik: I need to speed up my queries for performance reasons because my tables contain lot of data (more than 4 million rows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A database is designed to choose the fastest way to answer a question by itself. Assuming you use something like `WHERE indexed_column = 'value'`, Oracle will decide to use any index that will help all by itself; no need to specify it explicitly.

Comment: just to confirm with what you are saying, my select statement need not follow any particular rule to retrieve data from indexed columns, I can use SELECT statement in normal manner only. Performance optimization would be done automatically by oracle. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @user1466466 yes; indexed columns are no different from other columns, other than the fact that the database will have a separate database structure somewhere that allows it to quickly find rows for specific queries. Given your index and where clause above, Oracle will see that it has an index on the `name` column that would speed up the query and use it. You could verify this by making the database explain what it will do: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm