# How to get a mysql query to use a specific index?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

```
SELECT * FROM orders WITH (INDEX(idx));
```

When I fired above query I got the error

> mysql #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

I have created index as below

```
create index idx on orders(date,status);
```

Can anybody tell me the correct syntax?

Comment: can i only fetch date and status ?

Comment: Are you sure this is the MySQL index hint syntax?

Comment: can you tell me what is the error

Comment: ya sure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593765/how-to-use-index-in-select-statement

Comment: @viajy: no, not necessarily. If the optimiser thinks an index is narrow enough, and based on the expected returned rows it might use your index and then go to the table to retrieve the other values. But it depends....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the index is appropriate it will be used without explicitly specifying it.

Given you are using `SELECT *` I would not expect your index to be used (even if the INDEX hint had the correct syntax). The choice is down to the query optimiser's heuristics.

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT * FROM orders USE INDEX(idx);
```

Ref: [Index Hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html)

**Also, please note**: 99 times out of 100, specifying an Index hint should not be done. Let the optimiser do its job.

Comment: Thanks Bro it helps me to run execute sql query

Comment: not without more information. I would suggest asking a new question, with the relevant info

Comment: Yes. It's a reasonable question.