# myqsl: index for order by query

Tags: mysql, indexing

Here is the table_a schema I have:

| Field | type |
| --- | --- |
| id(PRIMARY) | bigint |
| status | tinyint |
| err_code | bigint |
| ... | ... |

The sql I want to execute will be:

```
select * from table_a where id > 123456 and status = -1 and err_code = 100001 order by id asc LIMIT 500
```

I'd like to query this sql above in real time.

My question is what kind of the index should I use here, I ready create a composite index -- idx_id_status_err_code, but it seems that mysql does not choose it.

There are two possible keys reported by explain statement -- PRIMARY and idx_id_status_err_code, but mysql use primary key instead of idx_id_status_err_code.

Another thing, there are some concurrent write operations, so I add row lock(for update not share mode) to target rows. I'm not sure if these write locks will affect the sql I mentioned above.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use `USE INDEX` hint. Please see [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-hints.html) for more information, or this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593765/how-to-use-index-in-select-statement)

Comment: @Hermanto Thanks! It works. Now it only takes 300ms. It seems that optimiser accept my suggestion, but I still want to know why mysql won't use it directly.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 1):

```
where id > 123456 and status = -1 and err_code = 100001 order by id
```

needs

```
INDEX(status, error_code,   -- 1st because they are tested with "=", either order
      id)  -- for range test (>) and for ORDER BY
```

Since that handles all of the `WHERE, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY`, the Optimizer can even handle the `LIMIT 500`, thereby stopping after 500 rows.

When you *start* an `INDEX` with the column(s) of the `PRIMARY KEY` (`id`), there is little reason for the Optimizer to pick the `INDEX` instead of simply reaching into the data.  This is especially true since you are fetching columns that are not in the index (`SELECT *`).

Avoid "index hints".  What helps today may hurt tomorrow (when the data distribution changes).

You mentioned a "row lock"; let's hear more about why you think you need such.  If you are afraid that some other thread will change one of the rows this `SELECT` picked, then that is better fixed by adding a suitable `WHERE` to the `UPDATE` -- to make sure the row still has that status and error_code.

Comment: Wow, this is clear. I try to add another index -- idx_status_err_code(since I need to query based on status and err_code in another query) and execute the query above. And this time, mysql use index_merge(Using intersect(idx_status_err_code,PRIMARY)) to optimize the query. 

As for row lock, its not related to the question above. I just don't know if this would affect optimizer to decide which index should be used.

Comment: Another Question, If I removed query condition 'err_code = 200001', like:
`select * from table_a where id > 123456 and status = -1 order by id asc LIMIT 500` 
this query will involve filesort, even if i try to change 'select *' to 'select id, status'.
Explain statement shows that this query only use idx_status_err_code, why mysql won't do index_merge this time to avoid filesort to 'select id, status'
Thanks!

Comment: "Using intersect" usually implies that you could benefit from a composite `INDEX` like the one I presented, but probably a different combination of columns.  The query you mention needs `INDEX(status, id)`; I expect this to avoid any "sort".  More:  [_Index Cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)